# Preparing a setup.py file with all the packages

Tags: python

I using Python2.7 to develop a project and also use VIRTUALENV part of it.

Now when I do pip freeze, it lists all the packages that was installed within my virtualenv...

Now, I need to create a setup.py file that will contain all the packages so that when other people working on the same project can download and just run python setup.py file so it installs all the packages..

What are the steps involved in it?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html this gives you a decent starting point, though some libs involved in it are somewhat outdated, the concept and general interfaces remain true. You can also take a look at one of those opensource examples with setup.py and how they did it. I recommend kennethreitz's `requests` or my `techies`. Both can be found on github :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question more directly, consider the following portions of content with 3 files involved.

In `requirements.txt`, specify one dependency per line, with optional version control

```
redis>=DESIRED_VERSION
```

In `MANIFEST.in`, specify one data file per line that should be included during setup and packaging process

```
include requirements.txt
```

In `setup.py`, simply read from `requirements.txt` to reduce the number of places you have to maintain the list of dependencies, and specify `install_requires` parameter in the `setup()` function

```
from setuptools import setup

# ...
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requires = f.read().strip().splitlines()
# ...

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=requires,
    # ...
)
```

Consider taking a look at those files from my project [`techies`](https://github.com/woozyking/techies) for a fully working example.